# Unable to set X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET headers in aws ses

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-ses, botocore

I am using this script to send email using AWS SES and I am able to receive email in my inbox but I am not able to see `X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET` header in the received email. I also tried using `Simple` email body type with `ConfigurationSetName` still no luck. **Any help is highly appreciated.**

```
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# Replace sender@example.com with your "From" address.
# This address must be verified with Amazon SES.
SENDER = "Niranj Raja <niranj@xxx.com>"

# Replace recipient@example.com with a "To" address. If your account
# is still in the sandbox, this address must be verified.
RECIPIENT = "niranj@xxx.com"

# Specify a configuration set. If you do not want to use a configuration
# set, comment the following variable, and the
# ConfigurationSetName=CONFIGURATION_SET argument below.
CONFIGURATION_SET = "test-me"

# The subject line for the email.
SUBJECT = "Amazon SES Test (SDK for Python)"

# The email body for recipients with non-HTML email clients.
BODY_TEXT = ("Amazon SES Test (Python)\r\n"
             "This email was sent with Amazon SES using the "
             "AWS SDK for Python (Boto)."
             )

# The HTML body of the email.
BODY_HTML = """<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <h1>Amazon SES Test (SDK for Python)</h1>
  <p>This email was sent with
    <a href='https://aws.amazon.com/ses/'>Amazon SES</a> using the
    <a href='https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/'>
      AWS SDK for Python (Boto)</a>.</p>
</body>
</html>
            """

# The character encoding for the email.
CHARSET = "UTF-8"

msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
# Add subject, from and to lines.
msg['Subject'] = SUBJECT
msg['From'] = SENDER
msg['To'] = RECIPIENT
#msg['X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET'] = CONFIGURATION_SET

msg.add_header('X-SES-CONFIGURATION-SET', CONFIGURATION_SET)

print(dir(msg))

print('')
# Create a multipart/alternative child container.
msg_body = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
print(dir(msg_body))
# Encode the text and HTML content and set the character encoding. This step is
# necessary if you're sending a message with characters outside the ASCII range.
textpart = MIMEText(BODY_TEXT.encode(CHARSET), 'plain', CHARSET)
htmlpart = MIMEText(BODY_HTML.encode(CHARSET), 'html', CHARSET)

msg_body.attach(textpart)
msg_body.attach(htmlpart)

# Create a new SES resource and specify a region.
client = boto3.client(
            'sesv2',
            aws_access_key_id='test',
            aws_secret_access_key='test1',
            region_name='region-10'
        )

# Try to send the email.
try:
    # Provide the contents of the email.
    response = client.send_email(
        FromEmailAddress=SENDER,
        Destination={
            'ToAddresses': [
                RECIPIENT,
            ],
        },
        Content={
            'Raw': {
               'Data': msg_body.as_string()
            }
        }
    )
    print(response)
# Display an error if something goes wrong.
except ClientError as e:
    print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
else:
    print("Email sent! Message ID:"),
    print(response['MessageId'])
```

Comment: Why should the received email still include the header? The header just controls the config set used for sending

Comment: I get your point @jordanm. But how do we know this is working? I have configured the rule set to send email to a specific address when it bounces, so do I need to send an email to see it bounces back successfully?

Comment: Experiencing the same issue here. I'm trying to receive info on Open and clicks. Cant see the header either. I have got a link but not sure what is happening? https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=955327